# What is the difference between KineticJS draw methods?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

What is the difference between KineticJS methods `layer.draw()`, `layer.drawScene()` and `layer.drawHit()`?

Comment: KineticJS is discontinued, KonvaJS is supported

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Have a look at the source (v4.3.1)](http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.1.js), l. 3381ff. These are defined on a `Kinetic.Container`.

```
    draw: function() {
        this.drawScene();
        this.drawHit();
    },
    drawScene: function(canvas) {
        // do stuff
    },
    drawHit: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
```

The `drawScene` is used to draw the shapes onto the drawing canvas.

The `drawHit` (see [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-custom-hit-function-tutorial/)) is used to allow to modify the region where mouse events trigger events. This is done internally using a special `Kinetic.HitCanvas`.

---

Update: You can find the code inside their [Github](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS) repository.
`draw()` can be found in [Node.js](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/Node.js), the other two inside [Container.js](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/Container.js)

Please be aware that Eric discontinued KineticJS.

Comment: Please if you can update the links as they are not working anymore

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib I've added some links to the GitHub repo.