# KineticJS - add shape to a layer that is already added to the stage?

Tags: kineticjs

I'm just starting with KineticJS, and as in the title, I can't add a shape to a layer if that layer is already added to the stage. This is probably for a reason, but I'd like to understand why.

This works:

```
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({container: 'canvas', width:200, height:200});
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var shape = new Kinetic.Wedge({x: 50, y: 50, radius: 30, angle: 60, fill: 'red'});
        layer.add(shape);
        stage.add(layer);
```

This doesn't:

```
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({container: 'canvas', width:200, height:200});
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);
        var wedge = new Kinetic.Wedge({x: 50, y: 50, radius: 30, angle: 60, fill: 'red'});
        layer.add(wedge);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct. It must work in **both** ways, you're probably just missing `stage.draw()` after adding the shape in the second case.

Edit 1:
For further reading regarding the `draw()` method, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886847/why-is-there-no-method-draw-in-kineticjs-documentation)

Comment: To elaborate, when you add a layer to the stage, it automatically draws the layer.  When you add a shape to a layer, it does not automatically draw the layer.